# How to use R for update and add data from the Bitrix24 REST-API?

Tags: r, httr, bitrix

The GET-function works well. So it is possible to get data from Bitrix (e.g. crm.lead.get), here the script:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
Url <- "https://bitrixxxxxxx.xx/rest/50/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/crm.lead.get.json?ID=2470"
GET(Url,accept_json())
```

But the update (crm.lead.update) does not work. Here is one try:

```
body <-'{ 
        fields: [
        { 
            "UF_CRM_1999999999999": "Text 1",  
            "UF_CRM_1999999999998": "Text 2"
        }   ] }'
or 
request_body <- data.frame(
  UF_CRM_1999999999999 = c("Text 1"),
  UF_CRM_1999999999998 = c("Text 2")
)
request_body_json <- toJSON(list(fields = request_body), auto_unbox = TRUE)     
body <- list(
                
                "fields" = request_body_json,
               "params" = request_body2_json
  )
or 
  body <-  '
    { 
      id: 2470,
      fields:
        { 
          "UF_CRM_1999999999999": "Text 1",  
          "UF_CRM_1999999999998": "Text 2"  
        },
      params: { "REGISTER_SONET_EVENT": "Y" }       
    }'
    
POST("https://bitrixxxxxxx.xx/rest/50/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/crm.lead.update.json?id=2470",encode="json",accept_json(),body=body)
```

The online-help from Bitrix24 ([Link to Bitrix](https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/crm/leads/crm_lead_update.php)) suggest the following solution:

```
    var id = prompt("Enter ID");
BX24.callMethod(
    "crm.lead.update", 
    { 
        id: id,
        fields:
        { 
            "STATUS_ID": "IN_PROCESS",  
            "CURRENCY_ID": "USD", 
            "OPPORTUNITY": 15500    
        },
        params: { "REGISTER_SONET_EVENT": "Y" }     
    }, 
    function(result) 
    {
        if(result.error())
            console.error(result.error());
        else
        {
            console.info(result.data());                        
        }
    }
);
```

I use for the crm.lead.update the PUT function and many combination for the body. Has anybody an idea for a solution or a template for r (crm.lead.update and crm.lead.add)?

Answer (score 0):

the issue that you're using the **PUT** method. I have checked the API doc page of Bitrix (https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/rest_sum/index.php), and it looks that it only accept **POST** or **GET** methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also tried GET and PUT. Probably every combination and it didn't work.